# Allowing Registered Users To Edit Only Specific JDatabase records?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jdatabase, fix-my-code

I have prepared a script which allows registered users to edit some records (which belong to them) in a table of JDatabase. Here's how?

**This is the first script which detects the logged in user and shows all the records present in the database belonging to that user in a HTML table** :

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__submission'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('username') . " = ". $db->quote($user->username));


    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadRowList();

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
echo ' <th>Project Name</th>';
echo ' <th> Details</th>';
echo ' <th> Action</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
foreach($rows as $row) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .$row['2']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['4']. "</td>";

echo "<td>";
// this hyperlink leads to the edit page of that specific record 
// $row['0'] returns the value of the id for that specific record
echo "<a href='edit.php?id={$row['0']}'>Edit</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

**Now this is the second script (edit.php)** :

```
<?php
// provides access to the database
include '/libs/connect.php';

if($_POST){
//update the record if the form was submitted
$sql="UPDATE `submissions` SET

Details='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Details']) . "'   
WHERE 
id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

if(mysql_query($sql)){
    //this will be displayed when the query was successful
    echo "<div>Record was edited.</div>";
}else{
    die("SQL: " . $sql . " >> ERROR: " . mysql_error());
}
}


  $id=$_REQUEST['id']; //the user id

//this query will select the user data which is to be used to fill up the form
$sql="select * FROM `submissions` WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$rs=mysql_query($sql) or die("SQL: ".$sql." >> ".mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($rs);

//just a little validation, if a record was found, the form will be shown
//it means that there's an information to be edited
if($num>0){ 
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
extract($row);
?>
<!--we have our html form here where new user information will be entered-->


<form action='#' method='post' border='0'>
<table>

          <tr>
        <td>Project Details</td>
        // displays a text box already having the value present in the database
        <td><input type='text' name='Details' value='<?php echo $Details;  ?>' /></td>
    </tr>


        <td></td>
        <td>
<!-- so that we could identify what record is to be updated  -->
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>' />

  <!-- we will set the action to edit -->
     <input type='hidden' name='action' value='edit' />
     <input type='submit' value='Edit' />
            <a href='/database.php'>Back to index</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </form>
```

Now, what exactly happens here is..

When the registered user, click on the edit button (on the main page - first script),
the URL becomes (example) :
`example.com/edit.php?id=3`

Now, the draw back here is if any one tries to reach this URL directly, even he will have the access to edit that record? I am confused, how can i allow only those records be edited which belong to the logged in user only?

Comment: Why in your first script have stuck to fairly good Joomla coding standards and then in your second script decided to use `mysql_*` functions? As for your actual question, you could either start a session and check the session on the edit page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are making this way too difficult.  Joomla provides you with a feature called ACL that allows just that.  For each record, Joomla will create an extra line in the `#__assets` table.

What you need to do is add an `asset_id` field to the database table:

```
`asset_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

create a role in a component (usually in a `/administrator/com_your_component/config.xml`) file as such:

```
<action name="core.edit.own" title="JACTION_EDITOWN" description="JACTION_EDITOWN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
```

then when you first create the record, if you inherit from jModelForm Joomla will take care of it; otherwise look at the store() method in

```
libraries/joomla/database/table.php
```

When you access it check the user can create new items in this section

```
       $authorised = $user->authorise('core.edit.own', 'com_your_component');
```

(you don't need to be inside your component to check it)

Please see the [official documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_ACL_rules_to_your_component) on using ACL and the [older version for J2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_ACL), which has more info.